# YouTube Video Info returning different results with Browser and WebRequest C#

Tags: c#, youtube, webrequest

I am using webrequests to get video data off of YouTube using the URL `http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id={ID HERE}`

When I visit the URL with a browser, it downloads the response file and all of the needed data is present. However, when I use an `HttpWebRequest` to download the response with a proper UserAgent, a lot of the data is missing.

The data that isn't present mostly involves locale information, browser version info (which I thought would come with the right UserAgent string but I guess not), and ids that refer to events created from the request.

My question is: Why is this data present in the version my browser downloads versus the WebRequest? How can I see what my browser is sending that makes it differ from the request I'm creating?

Here's how I'm currently requesting the data in C#:

```
        var url = string.Format("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id={0}", videoId);
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.UserAgent = userAgent;
        var response = request.GetResponse();

        string contents;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            contents = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: You can view the requests/responses from your browser and application using a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard WebRequest and browser request send different headers. You have to properly prepare your WebRequest (setup correct headers and cookies) to make the same HTTP request.

To see the difference, download Fiddler and open the same URL in browser, then in Visual Studio and compare both requests in raw text mode. You will note that WebRequest is missing a lot of headers.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser typically sends a longer query to `get_video_info` which includes locale and some kind of session identifier called `sts`.

To get `sts` I look for the json config on the watch or embed page and then search for a property called "sts".
You can use this regex to find it:

```
var sts = Regex.Match(html, @"""sts""\s*:\s*(\d+)").Groups[1].Value;
```

The locale/language is passed using query parameter called `hl`.

And then there are two other parameters `el` and `ps`, I have no idea what they do but somehow they influence the response as well. I just set them to predefined values.

Finally, the query string looks likes this:

```
"https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id={videoId}&sts={sts}&el=info&ps=default&hl={language}"
```